# ASP.NET 7 Action being called twice when Proxied using NGINX

Tags: c#, asp.net, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

A Post Action in my Asp.net 7 controller is being called twice when calling it from the proxied version.
When I make the post call on the IP:8001, the function is called only once.
But calling it on my, proxieddomain.com, the program seems to be receiving two requests (one after the other).

Here is my nginx config:

```
upstream webbusiness {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}

location / {
        proxy_pass         https://webbusiness;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Accept-Encoding "";
        access_log         /var/log/nginx/access-test.log combined;
    }
```

using the access log i have verified that the request from the client is received once but somewhere in between the nginx proxy forwarding that request to asp.net program, they are being duplicated.

ASP.NET Logs:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.0 POST https://proxieddomain.com/business/settemplateactive application/x-www-form-urlencoded;+charset=UTF-8 25
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware[10]
      No CORS policy found for the specified request.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController.SetBusinessActiveTemplate (WebBusiness)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[102]
      Route matched with {action = "SetBusinessActiveTemplate", controller = "Business"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] SetBusinessActiveTemplate(WebBusiness.Models.Template.SetActiveTemplateDataViewModel) on controller WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController (WebBusiness).
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Request: POST /business/settemplateactive from redactedpublicip
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Accept - application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Connection - close
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Host - proxieddomain.com
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: User-Agent - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Accept-Language - en-US,en;q=0.9
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Cache-Control - no-cache
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Content-Type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Cookie - session=redacted
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Origin - https://proxieddomain.com
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Pragma - no-cache
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Referer - https://proxieddomain.com/dashboard/2
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Content-Length - 25
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: X-Real-IP - redactedpublicip
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: X-Original-Proto - https
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: sec-ch-ua - "Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: X-Requested-With - XMLHttpRequest
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: sec-ch-ua-mobile - ?0
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: sec-ch-ua-platform - "Windows"
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: sec-fetch-site - same-origin
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: sec-fetch-mode - cors
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: sec-fetch-dest - empty
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: X-Original-For - 127.0.0.1:55018
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.SystemTextJsonResultExecutor[1]
      Executing JsonResult, writing value of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[105]
      Executed action WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController.SetBusinessActiveTemplate (WebBusiness) in 422.4906ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController.SetBusinessActiveTemplate (WebBusiness)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.0 POST https://proxieddomain.com/business/settemplateactive application/x-www-form-urlencoded;+charset=UTF-8 25 - 0 - application/json;+charset=utf-8 428.8991ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.0 POST https://proxieddomain.com/business/settemplateactive application/x-www-form-urlencoded;+charset=UTF-8 25
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware[10]
      No CORS policy found for the specified request.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController.SetBusinessActiveTemplate (WebBusiness)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[102]
      Route matched with {action = "SetBusinessActiveTemplate", controller = "Business"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] SetBusinessActiveTemplate(WebBusiness.Models.Template.SetActiveTemplateDataViewModel) on controller WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController (WebBusiness).
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Request: POST /business/settemplateactive from redactedpublicip
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Accept - application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Connection - close
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Host - proxieddomain.com
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: User-Agent - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Accept-Language - en-US,en;q=0.9
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Cache-Control - no-cache
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Content-Type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Cookie - session=redacted
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Origin - https://proxieddomain.com
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Pragma - no-cache
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Referer - https://proxieddomain.com/dashboard/2
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: Content-Length - 25
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: X-Real-IP - redactedpublicip
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: X-Original-Proto - https
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: sec-ch-ua - "Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: X-Requested-With - XMLHttpRequest
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: sec-ch-ua-mobile - ?0
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: sec-ch-ua-platform - "Windows"
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: sec-fetch-site - same-origin
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: sec-fetch-mode - cors
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: sec-fetch-dest - empty
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: X-Original-For - 127.0.0.1:55020
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.SystemTextJsonResultExecutor[1]
      Executing JsonResult, writing value of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[105]
      Executed action WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController.SetBusinessActiveTemplate (WebBusiness) in 2.6584ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController.SetBusinessActiveTemplate (WebBusiness)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.0 POST https://proxieddomain.com/business/settemplateactive application/x-www-form-urlencoded;+charset=UTF-8 25 - 200 - application/json;+charset=utf-8 3.2520ms
```

the logs do confirm that there are two requests being processed, another thing i noticed is, the first request is never sent back to the client but it is the second request that is sent back to the client.
We can see that the Header: X-Original-For has different port for both request, so could it be nginx causing the issue?

I have forwarded headers configured in my project using:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

I have tried messing with my nginx config but i can no seem to figure out where exactly this is happening, changing my forwarded headers config in asp.net.

And for now it seems that it is only this action that is being requested twice and not any other.

**Edit (Client closing before request finished):**

So upon further examination, it seems that the client is closing the connection before the request is completed by asp.net

logs:

```
....
info: WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController[0]
      Header: X-Original-For - 127.0.0.1:32918
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets[6]
      Connection id "0HMQCDHUCICVU" received FIN.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets[7]
      Connection id "0HMQCDHUCICVU" sending FIN because: "The client closed the connection."
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[10]
      Connection id "0HMQCDHUCICVU" disconnecting.
Console.WriteLine: ----------------------------------- returning function with response status code 200
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.SystemTextJsonResultExecutor[1]
      Executing JsonResult, writing value of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[105]
      Executed action WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController.SetBusinessActiveTemplate (WebBusiness) in 670.8894ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'WebBusiness.Controllers.BusinessController.SetBusinessActiveTemplate (WebBusiness)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST https://proxieddomain.com/business/settemplateactive multipart/form-data;+boundary=--------------------------203959939626907064415774 276 - 0 - application/json;+charset=utf-8 749.5827ms
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[2]
      Connection id "0HMQCDHUCICVU" stopped.
```

I have increased my timeout settings in the nginx block but still no luck:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass         https://webbusiness;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        client_max_body_size    10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_connect_timeout   2m;
        proxy_send_timeout      2m;
        proxy_read_timeout      2m;
        proxy_buffers           32 256k;
        access_log         /var/log/nginx/access-test.log combined;
        error_log          /var/log/nginx/error-test.log error;
    }
```